# Using OpenSSL without threads

Tags: windows, macos, sockets, openssl

Whenever I bash into OpenSSL on Windows or Mac I always make my own memory BIOs, and link them up to the platforms message based (asynchronous non blocking) socket implementation. (WSAAsyncSelect on windows: CFSocket on Mac)

[Secure programming with the OpenSSL API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html) hosted on ibm.com seems to be the best reference on implementing OpenSSL - but it implements a very simple blocking connection.

Is there a standard way to setup and use OpenSSL with non blocking sockets - such that calls to SSL_read will not block if there is no data for example?

Answer (score 1):

`SSL_read()` (and the other SSL functions) work fine if the underlying socket is set non-blocking.  If insufficient data is available, it will return a value less than zero; `SSL_get_error()` called on the return value will return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`, indicating what SSL is waiting for.

Comment: so I need to SSL_get_fd() and set it to non blocking?

Comment: @Chris Becke: I've always set the socket to non-blocking before passing it to `SSL_set_fd()`.  If you're using BIOs, you can just set your BIOs non-blocking with `BIO_set_nbio()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `BIO_set_nbio` with either `BIO_new_socket` or `BIO_new_connect/accept` is probably less code than creating memory BIOs. Not sure if there's anything more standard than that. The docs explain this in more detail:

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html

Comment: BIO_new_connect is definitely the canonical way to create a SSL Socket with OpenSSL. My query centers on: what is the best-practice / least-effort way to incorporate OpenSSL sockets into a program where SSL_read must not block.